# TFS Build not adding folder to SonarQube

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, alm

We have introduced SonarQube to our project integrated with TFS Build (2017).

That is our **project structure**:

[image]

SonarQube should run over **App**, **DotNetNuke** and **LotesKWKPortal**

The problem is that Sonar is adding only **KWKPortal** and **LotesKWKPortal**, the **App** folder is ignored:

[image]

Is this a problem with the Build definition or with SonarQube?

It seems like Sonar is only analysing folders with `.sln` files. How do I tell my TFS build to consider all folders in the repository?

**EDIT:**

That is how our build definition look like:[image]

Comment: How are you running SonarQube in your build process?

Comment: @DanielMann I just updated the post with an image of our build definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the SonarQube scanner for MSBuild tasks. Per the [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeExtensionforVSTS-TFS-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerCLITask), you should use the SonarQube CLI task for anything not touched by MSbuild, such as JavaScript.